# SQL - categorize rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Below is the result set I am working with.  What I would like is an additional column that identifies a X number of rows as the same.  In my result set, rows 1-4 are the same (would like to mark as 1), rows 5-9 are the same (mark as 2); row 10 (mark as 3)

How is this possible using just SQL? I can't seem to do this using rank or dense_rank functions.

```
ranking              diff        bool
-------------------- ----------- -----------
1                    0           0
2                    0           0
3                    0           0
4                    0           0
5                    54          1
6                    0           0
7                    0           0
8                    0           0
9                    0           0
10                   62          1
```

Comment: you mean row 6-9. row 5 is different

Comment: LivingThing, row 5 is when the change occurred so row 5-9 should be marked as the same thing.

Comment: Martin, this is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: @tadstones - But it changed again at 6.

Comment: Correct it changed again at 6, but everything from the first occurrence of 1 till the next one should be categorized together.  Hope that made sense

Comment: @tadstones, how do you know pnanny's DBMS and version?

Comment: and if you have two consecutive `1` how is that treated?

Comment: Consecutive 1 should be categorized differently

Comment: So this seems like a running total query summing the value of `bool` then adding one would give you the desired results? How many rows does this run over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general case you can do something like this:

```
select
    t.ranking, t.[diff], t.[bool],
    dense_rank() over(order by c.cnt) as rnk
from Table1 as t
    outer apply (
        select count(*) as cnt
        from Table1 as t2
        where t2.ranking <= t.ranking and t2.[bool] = 1
    ) as c
```

In your case you can do it even without `dense_rank()`:

```
select
    t.ranking, t.[diff], t.[bool],
    c.cnt + 1 as rnk
from Table1 as t
    outer apply (
        select count(*) as cnt
        from Table1 as t2
        where t2.ranking <= t.ranking and t2.[bool] = 1
    ) as c;
```

Unfortunately, in SQL Server 2008 you cannot do running total with window function, in SQL Server 2012 it'd be possible to do it with `sum([bool]) over(order by ranking)`.

If you have really big number of rows and your `ranking` column is unique/primary key, you can use recursive cte approach - like one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13744550/1744834), it's fastest one in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
;with cte as
(
    select t.ranking, t.[diff], t.[bool], t.[bool] as rnk
    from Table1 as t
    where t.ranking = 1
    union all
    select t.ranking, t.[diff], t.[bool], t.[bool] + c.rnk as rnk
    from cte as c
        inner join Table1 as t on t.ranking = c.ranking + 1
)
select t.ranking, t.[diff], t.[bool], 1 + t.rnk
from cte as t
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c765/3)</kbd>**